# How to bring through files after a certain date when using a SSIS Foreach Loop Container

Tags: ssis, ssis-2012, foreach-loop-container

Currently created an SSIS package that goes through a folder and brings back the latest file depending on the file name.  I've done this by using a Foreach Loop container

In testing it has worked fine, I've used about 20 files, all worked fine.  However when then trying to put this into the live environment, where it going through approx 200+ files, it's failing as the older files alter slightly, something I didn't know when first creating the package

I need to bring files through really only from the date 01/03/2020 onward, but cannot remove the older files from it's location

Is there a way I can alter the package to only bring back files from this date onward at all? And if so how would I do this?

Cheers in advance

Comment: Is 20200301 in the file name?

Comment: No just the date in SQL, removed to avoid any further confusion

Comment: I'm not following - if the date isn't in the file name and the format of the file has changed between the epoch date there, how can you tell what's in scope for processing versus out of scope?

Comment: It's ok, I sorted it in the end, I created a table for it to check against and manually inserted all the file names in there so it'll now skip past them all to the files I need

Also apologies, I didn't read your comment properly, the date was in the file name so for example the file names were in the format of , 'File_Name_2017-01-01', so I knew which files I needed to skip, but just wasn't sure how to do it, but the table to check if the file has been loaded or not has worked

Answer (score 0):

you can use file properties to get the latest file to process:

```
var directory = new DirectoryInfo("C:\\MyDirectory");
var myFile = directory.GetFiles()
             .OrderByDescending(f => f.LastWriteTime)
             .First();
```

you can also add a where in there:

```
var myFile = directory.GetFiles()
             .Where(f=>f.LastWriteTime>=DateTime.Parse("1/3/2020"))
             .OrderByDescending(f => f.LastWriteTime)
             .First();
```

Comment: Thank you @KeithL , what I have created works for now, however when I have more time I'll test this out! Thanks for posting